# Printing List Vertically/Centered - Pascal's Triange

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm pretty stumped on what seems to be a simple problem. Everything is computed and displayed correctly. I want it to print horizontally and centered. Also, a way to remove the brackets and commas would be plus.

```
from math import factorial
numcheck = False
while numcheck == False:
try:
    height = (raw_input("Input height of Pascal's Triangle (must be integer): "))
    height = int(height)
    numcheck = True
except ValueError:
    print "Not an integer!"
pascaltri = [[factorial(n) // (factorial(k) * factorial(n - k)) for k in range(n+1)]
 for n in range(height)]
print pascaltri
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140908/formatting-pascals-triangle) SO question about generating Ps triangle in python

Answer (score 1):

You could format it this way :

```
maxlen = len(" ".join([str(i) for i in pascaltri[-1]]))
formatted = '\n'.join([ " ".join([str(i) for i in line]).center(maxlen) for line in pascaltri])
print formatted
```

But have a look at Fredrik's link, there are many interesting ideas, including much more efficient ways to generate the triangle.